# First run of a Scheduled Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When is the first run of a Scheduled Firebase Cloud Function if it scheduled for every 33 minutes, 19 hours, etc. or immediately after deployment? I checked the docs but could not find any info.

Comment: There might not be a guarantee.  What happens if you simply deploy it?  What do you observe?

Comment: Actually there is no problem. It changes a lot from time to time. I just wondered if there is a logic or pattern behind it. It would be good to know when it will be active when we make an update in the function and deploy it again.